# Using a SubQuery in an Insert Statement in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a carsale project. It completely works on localhost. I have a "AddCar.aspx" page that inserts a car record with car's features. Car features are selected with checkboxes. If i don't check any checkbox, there is no problem. But if i check one of feature checkboxes, my page gives an error like this:

> "Subqueries are not allowed in this
>   context. Only scalar expressions are
>   allowed."

And my code is like that:

```
foreach (DataListItem item in Security1.Items) {
        CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("CheckBox1");

        if (CheckBox1.Checked) {
            HiddenField h = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("FeaID");
            string add = "Insert into Carfeature (RecID,FeatureID) values ((select Max(RecID) from record),@FeatureID)";
            cmd[k] = new SqlCommand();
            cmd[k].CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd[k].Parameters.Add("@FeatureID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = h.Value;
            cmd[k].CommandText = add;
            k++;
        }
}
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 8):

Two things, first of all, try this SQL:

```
Insert into Carfeature (RecID,FeatureID) 
select Max(RecID), @FeatureID from record;
```

Secondly, the `Max(RecId)` is problematic if you have multiple threads doing this. Are you aware that you can get the last inserted identity? Isn't that what you want to do here? If you've just inserted a record into the `record` table in the previous step

```
select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as RecID;
```

will give you the correct `RecID` in a thread safe manner.

Comment: never use @@identity to do this, use scope_identity instead. @@identity will give bad answers when someone puts a trigger on the table. Very bad practice to use @@identity for this purpose.

Comment: @HLGEM: Good suggestion. I updated my answer to use SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Answer (score 5):

Change your SQL to this:

```
Insert into Carfeature (RecID,FeatureID)
select Max(RecID), @FeatureID from record
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could just re-format your sql and do it this way:

```
Insert into Carfeature (RecID,FeatureID) select Max(RecID), @FeatureId from record
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to concurrency control. A way I'd recommend doing this on SQL Server 2005 is to change your sql statement to the following using CTE's(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
with MaxId as
(
  select Max(RecID)
  from record
)
insert into Carfeature (RecID,FeatureID)
select @MaxID, @FeatureID
from MaxId
```

Comment: -1 The problem is unrelated to concurrency, and the CTE adds nothing to the solution.  Wonder why this got voted up.

Answer (score 0):

Friends, you all answered true, thanks a lot.
I changed my code like that and it worked:

```
Insert into Carfeature (RecID,FeatureID) select Max(RecID), @FeatureID from record
```

But I don't know how to set accepted answer, because all of answers are true :)

Comment: When several answers are about as good, people generally mark the fastest answer as accepted

Comment: @Mehmet Kaleli: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check box next to the answer you want to accept.